# Is the equation pH + pOH = 14 valid at different temperatures?

Tags: acid-base, water, ph

> $\mathrm{pH} + \mathrm{pOH} = 14$

For water at 60 degrees Celsius,

$K_\mathrm{w} = 1 \times 10^{-13} = [\ce{H+}] \times [\ce{OH-}]$

Hence, $[\ce{H+}] = 1 \times 10^{-6.5} = [\ce{OH-}]$

So $\mathrm{pH} = -\log(1\times 10^{-6.5}) = 6.5 = \mathrm{pOH}$

which gives $\mathrm{pH} + \mathrm{pOH} = 6.5+6.5 = 13$, **not** $14$

So is my math or chemistry wrong, or are there limitations on $\mathrm{pH} + \mathrm{pOH} = 14$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> $\mathrm{pH + pOH = 14}$

This equation only holds true at around $25~^\circ\mathrm{C}$, where the water autodissociation constant $K_\mathrm{w} = 10^{-14}$.

Mathematically, you can write

$$\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] &= 10^{-14} & &\\
\log([\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]) &= \log(10^{-14}) & &\text{(logarithms of both sides)} \\
\log[\ce{H+}] + \log[\ce{OH-}] &= -14 & &(\log(ab) = \log a + \log b) \\
-\log[\ce{H+}] - \log[\ce{OH-}] &= 14 & & \\
\mathrm{pH + pOH} &= 14 & & \text{(definitions of pH and pOH)}
\end{align}$$

It's fairly clear from this that if $K_\mathrm{w}$ is $10^{-x}$ at some other temperature, then you will obtain $\mathrm{pH + pOH} = x$.

Comment: IOW, pH+pOH=-log(Kw).